# Select from Table Where field equals a variable

Tags: html, vbscript, asp-classic

From the following you will see that I have retrieved data from the table `school`. Next I am trying to derive data from the `class` table where the class relates to that school. To try and achieve this, I set a variable on a school being selected called `Scn`.

Alas, for whatever reason I can not get it to read the variable. The variable is confirmed as being set through an alert statement and I can select a class where the school equals (say) 1, but the for the love of all, I can't get the select statement to show data where the class equals the variable.

```
<SELECT NAME="ListBox1" SIZE=1 onchange="scname(this)">
<% Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") %>
<%conn.connectionstring = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" &_
"Data source = \\mockcourt.mdb"
Conn.Open%>



<% Set rs = conn.Execute("SELECT * FROM school") %>
<% Do While Not rs.EOF  ' define the ListBox OPTIONs %>
<OPTION VALUE="<%= rs("schoolKey") %>"> <%= rs("school") %>
<% rs.MoveNext %>
<% Loop %>
<% rs.Close %>
<% conn.Close %>
</SELECT>       

<script type="text/javascript">
function scname(target){
var Scn = target.value
alert("You changed to "+ Scn)
}
</script>

<SELECT NAME="ListBox2" SIZE=1 onChange="clname(this)">
<% Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") %>
<%conn.connectionstring = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" &_
"Data source = \\ mockcourt.mdb"
Conn.Open%>
<% Set rs = conn.Execute("SELECT * FROM class WHERE school = '"+Scn+"'") %>
<% Do While Not rs.EOF  ' define the ListBox OPTIONs %>
<% tba=Scn %>
<OPTION VALUE="<%= rs("school") %>,<%= rs("classname") %>"> <%= rs("classname") %>
<% rs.MoveNext %>
<% Loop %>
<% rs.Close %>
<% conn.Close %>
</select>
```

Comment: Ugh. I'm having a hard time debugging this with all your ASP code tags. Why are you using `<%` and `%>` on every line!?

Comment: @Bond has a point. Breaking up ASP processing tags (`<% %>`) in that way is incredibly inefficient due to IIS having to keep jumping to the ASP ISAPI extension to process the ASP code and switch back again.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. All taken on board.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that all your dropdwons is in the form named "myform" and form action either empty or defined as your page, try this:

```
  <% Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
 conn.connectionstring = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" &_
"Data source = \\ mockcourt.mdb"
Conn.Open
set rs=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset") 
dim Scn
Scn=request("ListBox1") & ""  ' to make sure that Scn is not null in any case

%>
<select  NAME="ListBox1" onChange="clname(this)">
<% Set rs = conn.Execute("SELECT * FROM school") 
  Do While Not rs.EOF  ' define the ListBox OPTIONs 
 if Scn=rs("schoolKey") then%>
     <OPTION VALUE="<%= rs("schoolKey") %>" selected> <%= rs("school") %></option>
 <% else %>
     <OPTION VALUE="<%= rs("schoolKey") %>"> <%= rs("school") %></option>
<%
  end if
  rs.MoveNext 
  Loop %>

  </SELECT>       
  <% set rs=nothing  %>
<script type="text/javascript">
function scname(target){
var Scn = target.value
alert("You changed to "+ Scn)
document.forms["myform"].submit();
}
</script>

<SELECT NAME="ListBox2" SIZE=1>    
<%
 set rs=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset") 
 Set rs = conn.Execute("SELECT * FROM class WHERE school = '"+Scn+"'")  
  Do While Not rs.EOF  ' define the ListBox OPTIONs 
  tba=Scn %>
<OPTION VALUE="<%= rs("school") %>,<%= rs("classname") %>"> <%= rs("classname") %></option>
<% rs.MoveNext  
  Loop %>

</select>
<% set rs=nothing

  conn.Close %>
```

it is considered a good practice to have HTML tags, inputs closed even images. And if you planning to ever work within companies where they have to obey certain standard make it your habit.

Comment: Thank you for the time to look into this for me. However, on reflection, I suspect I asked the wrong question?? Is not, that the code runs correctly, but as the user has not made a selection the variable Scn remains null and what I should be doing is adding something to the function Scname. Alas, I haven't a clue ... should it be a stored procedure or assigning the results to a new variable using SET and RETURN??

Comment: And could you be more specific what are you talking about? In my example Scn will never be a NULL, it would be either empty or have some value but not null ever. And your function Scname will submit form to itself now as soon as School name changed.

Comment: I accept my original question was flawed, it was only on receiving your initial response did I realise that I was looking at it incorrectly. Your assistance has been invaluable. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

`Scn` is declared within your `scname()` function. That means its scope is within that function and it cannot be used outside of it.